# HTML5 Canvas font gets blurry if added to a pdf file with jspdf

Tags: typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

I did build a function that scales the font size down till the text width is smaller then the canvas width. This font is getting added to a canvas that contains a qr code.

This canvas gets added to a pdf file.

The problem I have is that while the qr code stays crisp clean, the text will get blurry.

Here is a screenshot of the resulting qr code with text:

[image: code result]

For comparison, here is the qr code at the same size with the same font size created in word:

[image: word result]

Fullsize screenshots to see that they are the same size. Both taken from pdf file:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPlNt.png), [Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlyI0.png)

Here is the code that generates this qr code + text:

```
 printQRCode(){
const width = 150; // will be dynamic in the future
const ratio = 8 / 100;
const fontSize = width * ratio; // desired font size if the text fits the canvas
const text = `[${this.getCode()}]`;

toCanvas(text,
{errorCorrectionLevel: 'H', width},
(_err, canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas(ctx, fontSize, text, width); // shrinks the font size if the text is to long
  ctx.fillText(text, this.getCenterPositionForCanvasText(ctx, text, width), width - 5);
  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

  const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'a4');
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  pdf.autoPrint();
  pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
});
}

setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, fontSize: number, text: string, width: number){
    ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Arial';
    do{
      fontSize--;
      ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Arial';
    }while(ctx.measureText(text).width>width- Math.floor(width / 10));
  }
```

What do I need to change that the text isn't blurry anymore?

---

Edit:

I did log the dataURL of the canvas and the first thing I saw is that the original canvas is way smaller then the one that gets printed to the pdf file. I tryed to change the input unit of the png to 'pt'. That did make the canvas smaller but it is still bigger then the image from the dataURL.

How can I calculat how big the width and height needs to be that is passed to the png function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current workaround:

I changed the input unit format to px and calculate the size factor between the code generated and the original size from the dataURL and found that the code generated is exactly 1.7784 times bigger.

So I just divide the size with this factor

```
pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, Math.floor(canvas.width / 1.7784), Math.floor(canvas.height / 1.7784));
```

It will work. But I feel like that there is a better way to do that.

---

Edit:

I found the better way. When providing a width and heigth of 0, the size will be set to the actual size of the added image:

```
pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @KJ Which block exactly? The final block that is dispalyed in the pdf file? Could be because this workaround isn't very precise.

Comment: Will this really be a [problem](https://datagenetics.com/blog/november12013/index.html) if my qr code is only a little bit fuzzy? Also, when printing this qr code, the blocks are very crisp with no subpixels that I can see with my eyes. Only the text is a little bit blurry but it's not that bad.