# Canvar has blurry text when exported as png/printed

Tags: typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

*Followup to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911752/html5-canvas-font-gets-blurry-if-added-to-a-pdf-file/69912267?noredirect=1#comment123633529_69912267). I ask a new question because the error in my last question was related to the fact that jspdf enlarges the image when the addImage function is provided with the actuall size of the image.*

This is my new function that creates an QR code and add a text right under it:

```
  printQRCode(width: number): void {
    const text = `[${this.getNumberPath()}]`;

    qrcode.toCanvas(text,
    {errorCorrectionLevel: 'H', width},
    (_err: Error, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      this.setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas(canvas, text); // <= font will get set to ~"11px Arial" in my example
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width - 7);

      const win = window.open();
      win.document.write('<br><img src=\''+canvas.toDataURL()+'\'/>');
      win.setTimeout(() => win.print(), 0);
    });
  }

  setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, text: string): void {
    const fontFamaly = 'Arial';
    const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    const horizontalPaddingPtc = 0.10;

    // Set font size to 1px for calculation
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = `1px ${fontFamaly}`;

    const fontSize = canvasWidth * ( 1 - horizontalPaddingPtc) / ctx.measureText(text).width;
    ctx.font = `${fontSize}px ${fontFamaly}`;
  }
```

This code works as it should but there is a small catch: the text under the qr code is still a bit blurry.

To show how blurry it is, I first printed out the qr code and then I opened word and created the same text but in differend font sizes and also printed this out.

On the first look you can see that the text under the qr code is very blurry, even more blurry than a way smaller font size from word. Strangly, the QR code is very clean and looks perfect.

I placed both pages together into my scanner, so don't wonder why the image has a slight tilt:

[image: blurry font example]

Is there any way to make the text more clear?

Comment: Why add the text in the canvas? ... I would just add the text as a regular HTML element, and set style to adjust the font size, it will be a lot simpler than what you have in `setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas`

Comment: @HelderSepulveda But I have only a canvas element. I don't want to build more html elements inside the code just to add some text when canvas can also write text. Also the `setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas ` function is pretty simple. It's just a single calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that canvas only use a dpi of 96 when exporting it. So we need to make it bigger but shrink it back down before printing.

The trick is to create a bigger canvas and shrink it down when printing.

```
  printQRCode(width: number): void {
    const text = `[${this.getNumberPath()}]`;
    const scaleFactor = 4; // <= New scale factor
    toCanvas(text,
    {errorCorrectionLevel: 'H', width: width * scaleFactor}, // <= New factor here. canvas is 4x the size
    (_err: Error, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) => {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      this.setOptimalFontSizeForCanvas(canvas, text);
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
      ctx.fillText(text, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width);

      const win = window.open();
      
      win.document.write('<br><img heigth="'+canvas.height/scaleFactor+'" width="'+canvas.width/scaleFactor+'" src=\''+canvas.toDataURL()+'\'/>'); //<= shrink it back down when printing
      win.setTimeout(() => win.print(), 0);
    });
  }
```

The qr code gets a little bit blurry, but it's still very usable.

Left is the original, right the new one:

[image: originalqr] [image: newqr]

But the big diffence is the text. Top is old, bottom is new

[image: textold] [image: textnew]

If someone knows how to make the qr code to look crisp again or how to remove the little artifacts at the top of the text, let me know it.